Carrying over data retrieved from Firebase to another page
How do I use the same data from the selected item from the list below and display it on another page, similar to Intents in Android.
This is the layout of the list in HTML:
<body>

    <div>
        <img src="./res/Logo.png" alt="App Logo" class="logo">
    </div>

    <ul id="list"> 
      
    </ul>


</body>

And here is how the necessary data is being retrieved from Firebase:
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getDatabase(app);

function emergencyItemList(scenario, emergencyType) {
    var ul = document.getElementById("list");

    var li = document.createElement('li');

    var form = document.createElement('form');

    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = 'Vector.jpg';
    img.alt = 'Vector Icon';

    var pScenario = document.createElement('p');
    pScenario.innerHTML = 'Scenario: ' + scenario;

    var pEmergencyType = document.createElement('p');
    pEmergencyType.innerHTML = 'Emergency Type: ' + emergencyType;

    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = 'Maps.html';

    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.className = 'btn';
    input.type = 'submit';
    input.value = 'View Emergency Location';

    a.appendChild(input);

    form.appendChild(img);
    form.appendChild(pScenario);
    form.appendChild(pEmergencyType);
    form.appendChild(a);

    li.appendChild(form);
    ul.appendChild(li);
}

function fetchAllData() {
    const dbRef = ref(db, 'Admin Users/Emergencies');
    get(dbRef).then((snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
                let scenario = childSnapshot.val().Scenario;
                let emergencyType = childSnapshot.val().emergencyType;
                emergencyItemList(scenario, emergencyType);
            });
        } else {
            console.log("No data available");
        }
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
}

window.onload = fetchAllData;

I'm retrieving the data from Firebase, here is the schema:
"Emergencies": {
      "ETNQlDMHTcUPwWnAWteNBdznzNu2": {
        "Scenario": "Scenario 2",
        "emergencyType": "Medical Assistance",
      }
    }


Is there any way to do this similarly to what can be done for Android?

You will need to store the data somewhere on the client machine. I'd suggest encoding to JSON and putting it in localstorage. However if you're dealing with medical data (implied by the example) I'd be wary of what you're allowed to store

I'm only using the emergency status and what that scenario is, the user's personal information is also stored in that node.

"similar to Intents in Java" - (I assume you're referring to Android, not Java) -attaching data to a page load like this is typically implemented using the query string of a URL.  The intent data for an activity launch isn't stored inside the application.  If you want to persistently store data in your web app, you should look into local storage or indexdb. Or you can just query Firebase again in the other page.

I've looked into this a bit further, and it seems to be the way to go. Thank you for your responses!

Ofcourse we can do that in Android.
Here is an example.
XML code is as below.
<HorizontalScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/hView"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ly_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" />
</HorizontalScrollView>

Java code is as below.
final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
ly_container.removeAllViews();

Read Data from Firebase realtime database.
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("table").addValueEventListener (new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (MyUtils.cur_user != null) {
        array_user.clear();
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            for (DataSnapshot datas: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                User user = datas.getValue(User.class);
                
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell_user, null);
                
                TextView txt_name = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
                txt_name.setText(user.name);

                ly_header_container.addView(view);

            }
        }
    }

}
@Override
public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

}

});
As a result, we can see all users in horizontal scrollview
